# Nexus Mods Special Edition Cross Over

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nexus-mod-manager

I have the orginal Skyrim with Nexus Mod Manager and have downloaded about 126 mods.
I would like to use Special Edition but am concerned about two things.

So what I want to know is: Can I download Skyrim Special Edition and be able to keep my current mods from Nexus Mod Manager in my Special Edition game and not have to start Skyrim all over again in the Special Edition? Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more? What do you mean with Special Addition? Do you mean Skyrim Special Edition? Or do you mean Nexus Mod Manager's replacement, Vortex?

Comment: Oops! I am sorry! Special Edition. lol
Let me ask again.
I have Skyrim Elder Scrolls five and I have Nexus Mod Manager.
I have become aware that there is a Skyrim Special Edition for Nexus Mods.
So what I want to know is how can I download Skyrim Special Edition and be able to keep my mods from Nexus Mod Manager in my game and not have to start Skyrim all over again?
Is that possible?

Comment: I edited your question and merged you comment with it. Could you please confirm that this is correct? (and remove the comment?)

Answer (score 4):

Skyrim from 2011 (Oldrim) and Skyrim Special Edition (SE) should be seen as two different games. Save games are not compatible and by default, neither are mods, though some mods will be in some cases (with possible warnings though). Luckily, a lot of mod creators have ported their mods to the SE version of the game.

Nexus Mod Manager also won't understand that you want to 'reuse' the mods for SE.

You will have to restart playing and also have to restart installing all the mods you want for the SE. Some mods won't be available nor compatible.

I have both versions of Skyrim and I'm currently playing SE with 250+ mods. About 65% of the mods I used for Oldrim had a SE version that I could use, the rest was handpicked and configured together.

Comment: Where can I download the Skyrim Special Edition game?

Comment: Personally, I play it through [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/489830/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim_Special_Edition/). Currently it is on sale with a 60% off.

Comment: 65% of the mods I use aren't even available anymore, and half of those only run on a certain edition. For me, switching to SE is out of the question. And so is *not* starting a new game with the addition or subtraction of any mod ever, let alone that the OP needs to switch to using MO, and now they want to install a completely different game, +1. *"and not have to start Skyrim all over again?"* LOL... no. DL *Skyrim Unbound* and you'll get over that real quick. I start a new game like once a month; by then it's unstable anyway.